# Does this question have anything to do with Catalan numbers?

Tags: co.combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I think this question has something to do with Catalan numbers but I'm not really sure. I want to find out the number of strings that consist of $n$ $L$'s and $n$ $R$'s, under the constraint that for any given prefix, the number of unmatched $L$'s is atmost $a$ and the number of unmatched $R$'s is atmost b.

Comment: Sorry the formulation is slightly disorienting for me. Why do you say "$n$ pairs"? Do you just mean words of even length in the two letter alphabet?

Comment: Yes. Precisely, that.

Comment: But "n pairs" suggests more than "words of even length in the alphabet ${L,R}$.  It suggests exactly $n$ instances of $L$ and exactly $n$ instances of $R$.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is the same as walks from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,0)$ with steps of the form $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ that never go above the horizontal line $x=a$ and never go below the horizontal line $x=-b$.

Comment: @NathanReading In fact "$n$ pairs" can be understood in even more restrictive sense, e. g. forbidding $LLRR$ and allowing $LRRL$

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: Assuming that an $L$ can only be matched with a later $R$ (like parentheses), this is not quite the same as walks staying between $x=a$ and $x=-b$. For example, the string $RRRRLLLL$ stays between $x=0$ and $x=-4$, yet it has four unmatched $L$'s and $R$'s.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: True; OP should clarify.